How to add initial values to the UI list
I have not been able to figure out how to add initial values to the UI list until now, but now I know the answer.
I will note the code for the answer in the answer.

The easiest way to inscribe the initial values of the UI list would be to save them externally once.
For example, use a JSON file.
In short,
Execute the load script after registering the scene property
# Register classes only when the script is run independently
if __name__ == "__main__":
    
    register()
    # Execute the load script after registering the scene property
    writed_json()
    load()

Here is an example
import bpy,json

# Path to the JSON file
json_file_path = r"data.json"

def writed_json():
    import json

    # JSON data
    json_data = [
        {"name": "Cube", "info": "This is a cube", "show_in_panel": True},
        {"name": "Sphere", "info": "This is a sphere", "show_in_panel": False},
        {"name": "Cylinder", "info": "This is a cylinder", "show_in_panel": True},
        {"name": "Plane", "info": "This is a plane", "show_in_panel": False},
        {"name": "Torus", "info": "This is a torus", "show_in_panel": True},
        {"name": "Cone", "info": "This is a cone", "show_in_panel": False}
    ]

    # Save JSON data to a file
    with open(json_file_path, "w") as file:
        json.dump(json_data, file, indent=4)

def load():
    # Initialize
    my_list = bpy.context.scene.my_list
    my_list.clear()

    # Load data from the JSON file
    with open(json_file_path, "r") as file:
        json_data = json.load(file)
        my_list = bpy.context.scene.my_list

    for data in json_data:
        prop_name = data["name"]
        prop_info = data["info"]
        prop_show_in_panel = data["show_in_panel"]
        my_list = bpy.context.scene.my_list
        item = my_list.add()
        item.name = prop_name
        item.info = prop_info
        item.show_in_panel = prop_show_in_panel

        print("###load",
        prop_name,
        prop_info,
        prop_show_in_panel
        )
        bpy.context.scene.my_list_index = len(my_list) - 1

# Class for defining items in the UI list
class MyListItem(bpy.types.PropertyGroup):
    name: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Name")
    info: bpy.props.StringProperty(name="Info")
    show_in_panel: bpy.props.BoolProperty(name="Show in Panel")

# Class for defining a panel to display the UI list
class MY_PT_Panel(bpy.types.Panel):
    bl_idname = "MY_PT_Panel"
    bl_label = "My Panel"
    bl_space_type = "VIEW_3D"
    bl_region_type = "UI"
    bl_category = "My Addon"

    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout

        my_list = context.scene.my_list

        row = layout.row()
        row.template_list("MY_UL_List", "my_list", context.scene, "my_list", context.scene, "my_list_index")
        col = row.column(align=True)
        col.operator("my.add_item", icon='ADD', text="")
        col.operator("my.remove_item", icon='REMOVE', text="")

        if my_list:
            item = my_list[context.scene.my_list_index]
            layout.prop(item, "name")
            layout.prop(item, "info")
            layout.prop(item, "show_in_panel")

# UIList class for displaying the UI list
class MY_UL_List(bpy.types.UIList):
    def draw_item(self, context, layout, data, item, icon, active_data, active_propname):
        if self.layout_type in {'DEFAULT', 'COMPACT'}:
            layout.prop(item, "name", text="", emboss=False, icon_value=icon)
            layout.prop(item, "info", text="", emboss=False)
            layout.prop(item, "show_in_panel", text="", emboss=False, icon='HIDE_OFF' if item.show_in_panel else 'HIDE_ON')
        elif self.layout_type in {'GRID'}:
            layout.alignment = 'CENTER'
            layout.label(text="", icon_value=icon)

# Operator to add an item
class MY_OT_AddItem(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "my.add_item"
    bl_label = "Add Item"

    def execute(self, context):
        my_list = context.scene.my_list
        item = my_list.add()
        item.name = "New Item"
        item.info = "Information"
        item.show_in_panel = True
        context.scene.my_list_index = len(my_list) - 1
        return {'FINISHED'}

# Operator to remove an item
class MY_OT_RemoveItem(bpy.types.Operator):
    bl_idname = "my.remove_item"
    bl_label = "Remove Item"

    def execute(self, context):
        my_list = context.scene.my_list
        my_list.remove(context.scene.my_list_index)
        context.scene.my_list_index = min(max(0, context.scene.my_list_index - 1), len(my_list) - 1)
        return {'FINISHED'}

# Function to register classes
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(MyListItem)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_PT_Panel)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_UL_List)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_OT_AddItem)
    bpy.utils.register_class(MY_OT_RemoveItem)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_list = bpy.props.CollectionProperty(type=MyListItem)
    bpy.types.Scene.my_list_index = bpy.props.IntProperty()
    # Start the following initialization program after the scene properties have properly completed loading
    writed_json()
    load()

# Function to unregister classes
def unregister():
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MyListItem)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_PT_Panel)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_UL_List)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_OT_AddItem)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(MY_OT_RemoveItem)
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_list
    del bpy.types.Scene.my_list_index

# Register classes only when the script is run independently
if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()


AttributeError: '_RestrictContext' object has no attribute 'when a scene occurs
If you have trouble loading a scene,
timer can be used.
# accessing bpy.context here in the global scope, will raise an exception
#print(bpy.context.view_layer)

def on_register():
    # this will happen .01 seconds after addon registration completes.
    print(bpy.context.view_layer)

def register():
    bpy.app.timers.register(on_register, first_interval=.01)

https://blenderartists.org/t/how-do-i-solve-this-error-restrictcontext/1445005/4?u=makorin
